# jenkins:groovy sandbox is not permitting to use jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance

Tags: groovy, sandbox, jenkins-groovy

I have given a groovy script in my `deploy_job` to get the successful builds of my `build_job`. When I run the groovy script it's giving an error "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance"

I can run the script only by using groovy sandbox. I have no administrator rights to approve the script or to restart the Jenkins after doing any changes. I tried using try and catch blocks to catch the exception but it didn't work. Is there a way to whitelist the instance method?

```
def builds = []
def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("build_job")
job.builds.each {
    def build = it
    if (it.getResult().toString().equals("SUCCESS")) {
        it.badgeActions.each {
            builds.add(build.displayName[1..-1])
        }
    }
}
builds.unique();
```

Expected: Would like to whitelist `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem`

Actual: Failed to execute script

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins
> getInstance   at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:276)

Comment: You need to approve the usage of static method jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance. There is no other way around.

Comment: ok. Will check with my administrator. . thanks

Comment: using the above script i am receiving all the successful builds but how to have only successful build numbers of master branch

Answer (score 2):

In manage Jenkins go to In-Process Script Approval. There will be a list of of scripts and signatures awaiting approval. Approve the ones you have tried to use. You might have to do this multiple times for each step. You would do it for `getInstance` and the run fails and then you do it again for `getItem` and on and on until it clears.